# Difference String on Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two string that contain one and zeros. I want to determine how many chars are different the same position. 
For example:

"0000111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
AND
"0000000000000010000110000111100000000000000000000000000000000000"

The result is: 10

These strings' length are 64 always;

I can do it with loop which iterate over the string and count difference. but i want to do it with reg exp or another tool. The speed is important me. Because i have a lot of data to compare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast the strings to [`bit(64)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-bit.html), use [`bitwise XOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-bitstring.html), cast the result to `text` and count the `1` chars:

```
select length(replace(
    ( '0000111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'::bit(64)
    # '0000000000000010000110000111100000000000000000000000000000000000'::bit(64))::text,
    '0', ''))

 length 
--------
     10
(1 row)
```

Comment: replacing the '0' in the string and creating a new string is suboptimial.

Comment: @steve - In the answers we refer to the official distributions. This does not mean that you cannot propose an extension, be careful however with statements such as that something is suboptimal.

Answer (score 2):

klin's solution works for this particular problem.  A more general approach is to separate the values, one character per row, and count them:

```
select count(*)
from unnest(regexp_split_to_array('0000111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', ''),
            regexp_split_to_array('0000000000000010000110000111100000000000000000000000000000000000', '')
           ) u(a, b)
where a <> b;
```

I'm pretty sure klin's answer will be faster (although it is always worth testing such things).  But this is more general, in terms of the length of the strings and the values being compared.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store the data as strings, but as bit strings in postgres. This will enable you to call xor for the two strings and then you can can count the number of ones set.

The following page describes [bit strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-bitstring.html)
To count the bits sets you can write your own function or use the [pg_bitcount extension](https://github.com/thehyve/pg_bitcount)